# How to sort a Dart collection based on 3 items?

Tags: dart

Consider a `List<Point>`:

```
class Point {
  int x,y;
  int getManhattanDistanceTo(Point other) {
    return (x - other.x).abs() + (y - other.y).abs();
  }
  Point(this.x,this.y);
}
void main() {
  var points = [Point(0,0), Point(4,6), Point(9,23), Point(55,3)];
  // How to sort points based on distance from an arbitrary Point?
}
```

I'd like to sort the points based on their distance from an arbitrary `Point`.  I don't think implementing [Comparable](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Comparable-class.html) is a good idea.  Instead I could write a [Comparator](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Comparator.html), but I'm not sure how to consider the arbitrary point given that a `Comparator`'s signature only takes 2 items. I'd like to use a `Comparator` so I can call `List.sort(Comparator)`.

Am I stuck writing just a regular function such as `List<Point> sort(Point point, List<Point> points)`?

If anyone can think of a better title for this question, please edit it.

Comment: Something like this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/e9353a8b4ca7f7074ff10ada04c03443 helps?

Comment: @Luksprog: very clever!  If you put it in an answer, I'll mark it correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparable and Comparator are about comparing items against each other. If you need to do the comparison relative to outside information to the object you need to pass that in to the comparison operation. You can abstract this with the code below:

```
Function sortRelativeTo(Point reference) {
  int comp(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return p1
        .getManhattanDistanceTo(reference)
        .compareTo(p2.getManhattanDistanceTo(reference));
  }
  return comp;
}
```

which you can then use as:

```
Point reference = Point(xxx, yyy);
points.sort(sortRelativeTo(reference));
```